# import org.kie.internal.KnowledgeBase is not available in kie-api-7.45.0.Final.jar

Tags: drools, java-17, kie

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr12I.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbwOZ.png)I have currently updated Kie-apie and related drools dependencies to 7.45.0.Final.
After the update Maven throws error on building the project(error image attached).
Can someone suggest what is the replacement of these 2 classes if these are deprecated. I searched the web but couldnt get any answer which could help.

Thanks
Shivani

Comment: The package looks like its part of kie-internal artifact.

Comment: @seenukarthi, yes kie-internal is coming from drools-model-compiler which I have added in my pom <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-model-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>7.45.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: you shouldn't be relying on internal-only apis for this very reason -- they may disappear at any point and there's not going to be any migration guide for them. what exactly are you using them for?

Answer (score 0):

As a comment noted, you shouldn't be using internal API.

Consider using KIE API for instance instantiating `KieContainer` from KJAR maven gav coordinates:

https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_kiecontainer_from_kierepository

or, if you really have a strict requirement to build from files, use public programmatic API: https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_programmatically_build_a_simple_kiemodule_with_defaults

you will find these examples here: https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/tree/7.x/drools-examples-api